# Why does content wrap after transition?

Tags: html, css, transform

I did my best to strip down my problem into a mwe.

The issue is happening where I have an ascii character for male (♂) which is behaving differently than the emojis. This problem only happens with ascii character. The container is supposed to have 100% the height of the header, and maintain an aspect-ratio of 1. It does not do this on the first render. However, there is a transform to the `.ul-title` element and when it reverts after transforming on hover, the following element seems to have the height re-calculated and the width adjusted. However, because of this, the width of `.ul-title` which was set to `max-content` is changed or something and the content ends up wrapping.

I want to have the animation effect, and not wrap the text. I want to have the `.tag` elements all be square. I have considered using javascript to hard set the values for width and height, but I feel like there should have been a css fix. Any pointers are appreciated

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 1rem;
}

.ul-title {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width: max-content;
}

.ul-title:hover {
  transform: translate(3px, 0);
}

.ul-title::before,
.ul-title::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 1px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.ul-title::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.ul-title::after {
  width: 10%;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

header li.tag {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 black;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li class="ul-title">Popular Tags</li>
    <li class="tag">♀</li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, none of the characters has the desired box. Although the aspect ratio is set to 1 they are not square.

There is no explicit height set.

It depends on exactly what effect you require, for example if different icons with different characteristics are added, but this snippet simply sets a height of 1.5em to the list and makes sure each character is centred by setting li elements to flex.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 1rem;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.ul-title {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width: max-content;
}

.ul-title:hover {
  transform: translate(3px, 0);
}

.ul-title::before,
.ul-title::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 1px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.ul-title::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.ul-title::after {
  width: 10%;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

header li.tag {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 black;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li class="ul-title">Popular Tags</li>
    <li class="tag">♀</li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
    <li class="tag"></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: I see, so even though I set the height to 100% and the header had a height from content being inside it, unless I explicitly set the height to a value, it will not inherit `100%` as a meaningful value? Where your context of assigning `ul` to have a specific height gave meaning to the `100%`